# Why does `go test` not work outside go module folder?

Tags: go, neovim, delve

I have then follwing repo structure:

```bash
.git

mysrc/
  |- go.mod
  |- a/some.go
   ...
```

in my repo. When I am inside the repo and execute `go test mysrc/a` , it does not work.
as `go` tells me it cannot find the `go.mod` file.

```bash
go: cannot find main module, but found .git/config in /home/nixos/Desktop/Repos/myrepo
        to create a module there, run:
        go mod init
```

But the normal `cd mysrc && go test a` works fine.

How can I execute `go test` inside the root folder.

PS: I need this to make the debug adapter `nvim-dap` configurations work, which starts `dlv` inside the root repo which build with `go build -o __debug_bin2596382558 -gcflags all=-N -l ./mysrc/a`

Comment: Your working directory must be within the module for the `go` command to know what module to use. ([go.mod](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-The_go_mod_file), _"When the go command is run, it looks in the current directory and then successive parent directories to find the go.mod marking the root of the main (current) module."_)

Comment: ok, sure. I thought I can somehow tweak it with a argument or env variable..., somehow I cannot tweak the dap adapter.

Comment: You can change the current directory of the command with the `-C` flag: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies

Comment: ok yes, I could also run `delve` with additional compile arguments like you said I guess. My answer below however works for the debug adapter.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the following `dap` configuration for `go` in `nvim` with `mfussenegger/nvim-dap`

```lua
dap.configurations.go = {
  -- This are the requests documented here:
  -- https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/api/dap/README.md
  -- works with go.mod packages and sub packages
  {
    type = "delve",
    name = "[githooks] Debug Test (go.mod)",
    request = "launch",
    mode = "test",
    program = "${fileDirname}",

    -- Because we are in a subdirevtory, this is needed.
    dlvCwd = "mysrc",
  },
}
```